# Doing a "WHERE IN" clause with Spark, how may I retrain only the columns of my first dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Am I doing things correctly ?

I would like to retain only `mobilite` data that are related to the cities mentioned in `communes`.
I simulate the `WHERE ... IN ...` clause by a `join` : is it the best way to do it ?

```java
Dataset<Row> mobilite = this.mobiliteDomicileTravailDataset
   .dsRowFluxDomicileTravailPlusDe15ansAvecEmploi(this.session, 2017);

Dataset<Row> communes = communes(2018);

mobilite = mobilite
  .join(communes, 
        communes.col("codeCommune").equalTo(col("code_commune_origine")), "inner")
  .selectExpr("mobilite.*");
```

The `mobilite` dataset taken just after the `join` operation have the `communes` columns inside. It's normal. But they do not interest me. However, what I've wrote doesn't work and leads to an error.

How do I discard them quickly ?
What is the quickest code to write to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `leftsemi` join:

```
mobilite = mobilite
  .join(communes, 
        communes.col("codeCommune").equalTo(col("code_commune_origine")), "leftsemi")
  .selectExpr("mobilite.*");
```